# Escape whole find content to send it to a command over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, escaping

I'm trying to use a ssh command like :

```
ssh user@host command -m MYFILE
```

MYFILE is the content of a file on my local directory.

I'm using Bash. I've tried to use `printf "%q"`, but i'd not working. MYFILE contains spaces, new lines, single and doublequotes...

Is there a way my command gets the file content ? I can't actually run anything else than `command` on the remote host.

Comment: What is `command`? are you talking about the Bash builtin?

Comment: `command` is a command I launch on the remote host. For my use case, it's `gerrit review`. It takes an argument `-m` with is a message.

Comment: & `gerrit review` is a real command (a file), not bash function or alias, right?

Comment: @anishsane I'm not sure what it is. It's a custom ssh server made for gerrit, I'm not sure there's actually a filesystem at all behind it.

Comment: Have you tried: `ssh user@host command -m "$(printf '%q' "$(cat MYFILE)")"`?

Comment: You could also use `"$(< MYFILE)"` instead of `cat` in @gniourf_gniourf's suggestion to avoid the external process.

Comment: You can try to do something like: `ssh user@host command -m /dev/stdin < MYFILE`

Comment: What is the operating system on the remote host? Is it linux or something else unix-like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about first transferring the file to the remote machine

```
scp MYFILE user@host:myfile &&
ssh user@host 'command -m "$(< myfile)" && rm myfile'
```